# std::bind and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, stdbind

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <functional>

template<class ...Args>
void invoke(Args&&... args)
{
}

template<class ...Args>
void bind_and_forward(Args&&... args)
{
    auto binder = std::bind(&invoke<Args...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    binder();
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    bind_and_forward(a, 2);
}
```

If I understand correctly, the reason is as follows: `std::bind` copies its arguments, and when the `binder`'s `operator()` is called, it passes all the bound arguments as *lvalues* - even those ones that entered `bind` as *rvalues*. But `invoke` was instantiated for the original arguments, and it can't accept what the `binder` attempts to pass it.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct - `bind` copies its arguments. So you have to provide the correct overload of `invoke()` that would be called on the lvalues:

```
template<class ...Args>
void bind_and_forward(Args&&... args)
{
    auto binder = std::bind(&invoke<Args&...>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                                    ^^^^^^^^
    binder();
}
```

This works on most types. There are a few exceptions enumerated in [func.bind.bind] for [`operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind#Member_function_operator.28.29), where `Arg&` is insufficient. One such, as you point out, is `std::reference_wrapper<T>`. We can get around that by replacing the `Args&`usage above with a type trait. Typically, we'd just add an lvalue reference, but for `reference_wrapper<T>`, we just want `T&`:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct invoke_type 
: std::add_lvalue_reference<Arg> { };

template <typename T>
struct invoke_type<std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    using type = T&;
};

template <typename T>
using invoke_type_t = typename invoke_type<T>::type;
```

Plug that back into the original solution, and we get something that works for `reference_wrapper` too:

```
template<class ...Args>
void bind_and_forward(Args&&... args)
{
    auto binder = std::bind(&invoke<invoke_type_t<Args>...>, 
                            //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    binder();
}
```

Of course, if one of `Arg` is a placeholder this won't work anyway. And if it's a bind expression, you'll have to write something else too.

Comment: But in such a case it won't compile for an argument wrapped with `std::ref()`.

Comment: @IgorR. Updated for that one - `bind()` does something special for `std::ref()`. So you'd have to do something special too.